# Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

When i creat a realtime database table then i get the table datas but i got an error: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast

```
FirebaseAnimatedList(
        query: dbRef,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
          Animation<double> animation, int index) {
        Map data = snapshot.value as Map;
        data['key'] = snapshot.key;
        return listItem(data);
         },
      ),
```

I got Result

[image]

Comment: Can you include your console database structure, what is your query

Comment: The error is pretty clear. It says that snapshot.value is a String and not a Map. Just work from there. Investigate what you are actually get it. For example print(snapshot.value)

Answer (score 0):

Here snapshot.data is a map and snapshot.value is string

Try

```dart
Map data = snapshot.data as Map;
```

Comment: i don't get snapshot.data

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the dynamic value which comes in string into decoded jsonMap if it is a map using `jsonDecode`. Or, you can use snapshot.data which comes in terms of key, value pair Map.

```dart
FirebaseAnimatedList(
        query: dbRef,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
          Animation<double> animation, int index) {
        Map data = jsonDecode(snapshot.value.toString());

// or
Map data = snapshot.data;


// Now do what you want to do
        data['key'] = snapshot.key;
        return listItem(data);
         },
      ),
```

Comment: i want show firebase data

Comment: i don't get snapshot.data

Comment: try to jsonDecode and see if the data comes there.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query returning single value,
First test with it

```dart
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
    Animation<double> animation, int index) {
  return Text("${snapshot.value}");
},
```

Now for getting map, it is possible to get null value, for this case do

```dart
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
    Animation<double> animation, int index) {
  Map? data = snapshot.value as Map?;
  final String? key = snapshot.key;
  return Text("Your ItemBUilder : $key ${data.toString()}");
},
```

Comment: i got result,but also show error message

Comment: What is the issue? I think issue refers to your query ?